# load javascript function in script with media queries

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I was wondering how to load a Javascript with media queries.

This is what I have:

```
<script src="js/jqfunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>;
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document.ready(function() {
        if (matchMedia) {
            var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)");
            mq.addListener(WidthChange);
            WidthChange(mq);
        }
        function WidthChange(mq) {
            if (mq.matches) {
                activateslideup();  
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: While you can get this to work - how are you going to unload the Javascript when the browser is resized? How are you going to undo functionality it has already introduced? What happens when you reload the JS several times. You should write good JS that responds to `resize` events, not hack it like this. It will never work well on a resizable browser (which is essentially every browser - even smartphones and tablets can switch orientation).

Comment: Didn't think about that. I'm new to Javascript and trying to combine RWD with Javascript

Comment: How about using functions instead of script? (edited question)

Comment: Some good help here which I have used http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/08/combining_media.html